# Fetching an image from array of images and redirect it to another page to display

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am working in jsp... I have a page called first.jsp in it I am displaying bunch of images by using following code:

```
<img src="a\<%out.println(s5[j]);%> "  width="200" height="200"  onclick="myfunction()"  id="abc"    />
```

Here a is folder's name where all images resides. Now s5[j] is array of image files which I am accessing using for loop.. (image tag is within for loop)

Now my question is that I want  to access one of the image which user has clicked to select and forward it to second.jsp page which display that particular image.

I want to do this by  javascript by onclick() function which I have displayed in code line.. But when I do that by document.getelmentbyid("abc").src it displays only first image regardless of any other images user selcted...

What to do???

Comment: what you have in myfunction ? you need to make change in on click event handler

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question that image tag is in a loop. In a page you can not have elements with same id. ID should be unique to the page. You can give a css class to those image and you can try
 $('.classname').click(function(){
// this will return you an array . you can check which is clicked here and send it to next page
});

Answer (score 0):

You can't get clicked image src with ID attribute, insted use `this.src`

```
var myfunction = function(){
       var src =  this.src
       //rest of the code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit of unclear what do you mean by forwarding image to second.jsp page.But have look at below

**1** you can't give id to multiple img tags. so just remove id and use class instead

```
<img src="a\<%out.println(s5[j]);%> "  width="200" height="200"  onclick="myfunction()"  class="abc"    />
```

**2** in myFunction() write down :

```
function myFunction(){
 //this refrence to img tag
 var img = this;
 // do wahtever you want to do
 var src = img.src;
}
```